# Any idea on how to monitor multiple jenkins instances via a single jenkins job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-job-dsl

I want to have a Jenkins job to monitor other Jenkins instances of performance.
so that I have details of all the instances at once place.
Any suggestions in that regard.

Answer (score 0):

https://medium.com/@eng.mohamed.m.saeed/monitoring-jenkins-with-grafana-and-prometheus-a7e037cbb376
This would be a good solution for what you're trying to achieve.
You can have a dashboard for each instance inside Grafana

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info @chris,  But currently we are not looking for a complete stack. But just a job in Jenkins which can just fetch performance details and compare it against our static thresholds.

Comment: @Shell_Magic can you be more specific on the performance? What kind of performance do you want to monitor?

Comment: Hello Chris .. So what i mean exactly is say I have  nodes running in a exact same environment.. i want to monitor the performance via few parameters like download speed, cpu load, compilation time for each of the nodes and then have these values for comparison of their performance so basically its for node performance monitoring.